# How can I make an enamel-on-steel bathtub feel/sound more substantial?

Tags: bathtub

I'm installing an enamel on steel bathtub on a concrete slab. Any good ideas for what can I do to make it feel and sound less flimsy and hollow?

Edit: How about lead diving weights as harmonic dampers, attached to underside of tub with structural adhesive, surrounded/supported by Great Stuff foam, on top of a bed of scrap pressure-treated 2x4--I imagine that's a bad idea for some reason(s), but I propose it as a serious question. Why not?

Comment: Spray foam all of the underside. The type of foam you need and the cost involved may cost more than getting a cast iron tub to begin with.

Comment: Spraying foam is a good idea, but be ready for the foam to expand; I've seen tubs lifted off their foundations by over-enthusiastic foam application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bed it in plaster (which is very likely what the tub manufacturer recommends - most do.) Foam can work but is not preferred (easier when you have an already installed tub, though.)

Bedding on plaster is literally get ready to go, test fit, dump a pile of plaster on the floor under the middle of where the tub goes, set the tub. Tub ends up solid, you don't have anything that's going to rot in there, and the plaster is easily broken out when the tub eventually needs to be replaced.

As for your cockamaimie scheme, the diving weights alone will cost more than the bag of plaster; and it's an ugly mess and waste of effort .vs. doing it right with plaster.