# Bathtub flex when used

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

I have a bathtub that was installed with only basic supports that came with it. It's my understanding the best way to support tubs is over a bed of portland cement.
Whenever someone is in it, I can hear it flexing. It is upstairs, so it's installed on subfloor.

I have access to the front of it. Is there a way to add support to it without having to remove the entire tub?

Comment: Plaster is the old-school way, cement or mortar seem to be a modern misinterpretation - foam is also a possibility. Let me find one of the duplicates. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/74644/18078 • https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11790/18078

Comment: Thanks. Foam helped